# Falling Snow Effect not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I manage a few websites and for some reason I am having trouble getting the falling snow effect to work in Google Chrome. The code works perfectly in IE 11 but the same exact code in Google Chrome just puts a snowflake in the upper left corner of the page. Is my code wrong for it to work in Chrome?

CSS

```
    .snowflakeContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
.snowflake {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    position: fixed;
    color: #008B8B;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.snowflake:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="js5/fallingsnow_v6.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
// The star of every good animation
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

var transforms = ["transform", 
                  "msTransform", 
                  "webkitTransform", 
                  "mozTransform", 
                  "oTransform"];

var transformProperty = getSupportedPropertyName(transforms);

// Array to store our Snowflake objects
var snowflakes = [];

// Global variables to store our browser's window size
var browserWidth;
var browserHeight;

// Specify the number of snowflakes you want visible
var numberOfSnowflakes = 25;

// Flag to reset the position of the snowflakes
var resetPosition = false;

//
// It all starts here...
//
function setup() {
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", generateSnowflakes, false);
    window.addEventListener("resize", setResetFlag, false);
}
setup();

//
// Vendor prefix management
//
function getSupportedPropertyName(properties) {
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (typeof document.body.style[properties[i]] != "undefined") {
            return properties[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//
// Constructor for our Snowflake object
//
function Snowflake(element, radius, speed, xPos, yPos) {

    // set initial snowflake properties
    this.element = element;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;

    // declare variables used for snowflake's motion
    this.counter = 0;
    this.sign = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1;

    // setting an initial opacity and size for our snowflake
    this.element.style.opacity = .1 + Math.random();
    this.element.style.fontSize = 12 + Math.random() * 50 + "px";
}

//
// The function responsible for actually moving our snowflake
//
Snowflake.prototype.update = function () {

    // using some trigonometry to determine our x and y position
    this.counter += this.speed / 5000;
    this.xPos += this.sign * this.speed * Math.cos(this.counter) / 40;
    this.yPos += Math.sin(this.counter) / 40 + this.speed / 30;

    // setting our snowflake's position
    setTranslate3DTransform(this.element, Math.round(this.xPos), Math.round(this.yPos));

    // if snowflake goes below the browser window, move it back to the top
    if (this.yPos > browserHeight) {
        this.yPos = -50;
    }
}

//
// A performant way to set your snowflake's position
//
function setTranslate3DTransform(element, xPosition, yPosition) {
    var val = "translate3d(" + xPosition + "px, " + yPosition + "px" + ", 0)";
    element.style[transformProperty] = val;
}

//
// The function responsible for creating the snowflake
//
function generateSnowflakes() {

    // get our snowflake element from the DOM and store it
    var originalSnowflake = document.querySelector(".snowflake");

    // access our snowflake element's parent container
    var snowflakeContainer = originalSnowflake.parentNode;

    // get our browser's size
    browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    // create each individual snowflake
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSnowflakes; i++) {

        // clone our original snowflake and add it to snowflakeContainer
        var snowflakeCopy = originalSnowflake.cloneNode(true);
        snowflakeContainer.appendChild(snowflakeCopy);

        // set our snowflake's initial position and related properties
        var initialXPos = getPosition(50, browserWidth);
        var initialYPos = getPosition(50, browserHeight);
        var speed = 5+Math.random()*40;
        var radius = 4+Math.random()*10;

        // create our Snowflake object
        var snowflakeObject = new Snowflake(snowflakeCopy, 
                                            radius, 
                                            speed, 
                                            initialXPos, 
                                            initialYPos);
        snowflakes.push(snowflakeObject);
    }

    // remove the original snowflake because we no longer need it visible
    snowflakeContainer.removeChild(originalSnowflake);

    // call the moveSnowflakes function every 30 milliseconds
    moveSnowflakes();
}

//
// Responsible for moving each snowflake by calling its update function
//
function moveSnowflakes() {
    for (var i = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
        var snowflake = snowflakes[i];
        snowflake.update();
    }

    // Reset the position of all the snowflakes to a new value
    if (resetPosition) {
        browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight; 

        for (var i = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
            var snowflake = snowflakes[i];

            snowflake.xPos = getPosition(50, browserWidth);
            snowflake.yPos = getPosition(50, browserHeight);
        }

        resetPosition = false;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(moveSnowflakes);
}

//
// This function returns a number between (maximum - offset) and (maximum + offset)
//
function getPosition(offset, size) {
    return Math.round(-1*offset + Math.random() * (size+2*offset));
}

//
// Trigger a reset of all the snowflakes' positions
//
function setResetFlag(e) {
    resetPosition = true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Again the code works well in IE11 but the same exact code will not work in Chrome.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Does *anything* happen? Are there errors reported in the console? Does it work in Firefox?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0La6jgkh/

Comment: Where is your "snowflake" element in your HTML above?

Comment: Works in Chrome for me. Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I am not getting any console errors, just a single snowflake appears in the upper left hand corner and no animation, now I am wondering if it is because this version of Chrome is a managed version of Chrome my company has set for us to use. :(